# filling a combobox in vbnet when combobox is in a groupbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a generic routine to fill comboboxes when the form loads.  I get the data from MySql and fill the comboboxes, but it does not work for any combobox inside a groupbox.  Tried passing in formname, groupbox name, comboname byVal and byRef, tried passing in as objects, strings, controls, tried various ctypes and trycast, can't seem to find the magic syntax.  I have a  test form with 2 comboboxes, one outside and one in a groupbox and this code.

```
Public Function TESTloadComboBoxOrHelp(ByRef formName As Form, ByVal boxName As Object, ByVal callingName As String) ', ByVal groupBx)
    'loadComboBoxOrHelp(me,"comboboxname",me.name)
    'tried passing byVal and byRef, no difference
    'frmCmbTest has 2 combo boxes, one in a groupbox and one not in groupbox, the one NOT in works
    '
    If formName.Name.ToString = "frmCmbTest" Then
        CType(formName.Controls(boxName), ComboBox).Items.Add("ABC") '  1: this WORKS because combobox1 is NOT in a groupbox BUT does not work for combobox2 in groupbox
        frmCmbTest.ComboBox2.Items.Add("ZYZ") ' 2: NOT Generic, this WORKS even though combobox2 is in a groupbox so why does line 1: above NOT work for a groupbox ?
        'formName.boxName.Items.Add("ZYZ")    ' 2.1: this does NOT work even though its the equivalent syntax (didn't expect it to)
        'formName.groupBx.boxName.Items.Add("ZYZ")    ' 2.2: NOPE, Tried passing in the name of the groupbox
        'frmCmbTest.CType(formName.controls("Groupbox1"), GroupBox),CType(formName.Controls.boxName.Name.ToString), ComboBox).Items.Add("DEF") ' 3: so of course this should not work, tried to replicate line above (2:) could not figure out syntax that would work.
        'frmCmbTest.GroupBox1.ComboBox2.Items.Add("ZYZ") ' 4: does not work, as is expected not to.
        'TryCast(formName."GroupBox1".Controls(boxName.Name), ComboBox).Items.Add("MNO") '5: I am guessing I need to add the groupbox name somewhere
        TryCast(formName.Controls(boxName), ComboBox).Items.Add("MNO")  ' 6: out of ideas, works for combobox1 not in groupbox, does not work for combobox2 in groupbox1
    End If
    Return 1
End Function
```

Currently I have 5 functions, one generic one for filling comboboxes that are not in groupboxes on various forms and the 4 functions that are not generic and its driving me crazy.

Comment: you are making it too complicated.  1) why not just bind the CBOs if the data source is a DB?  2) Barring that, since you want the data to go into a SPECIFIC cbo, write a sub to post the data passing the DS/DT and CBO object reference.  All the find control by formname and control name is confusing you.

Comment: not sure why you are doing this when you only have 1 form? you can just name your combobox and fill it and it does't matter if it is in a groupbox or not. Just plain combobox1.items.add() / combobox2.items.add() should do

Comment: I have several forms and I had not thought of binding it, I am so used to just doing plain old SQL that I didn't think of that.  I will look into it since it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with 2 different [`ControlCollections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), since it appears that you are using Windows Forms, the Control Colllection has a [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will check if the item is in the parent collection and its Children. It will return an array of all of the matches so make sure that your device names are unique and not a subset of each other. *i.e. boxName and boxName1 searching for boxName with give you a result with 2 items*

```
Dim c As Control() = Controls.Find("boxName", True) 'Search for boxName in parent and all child controls
If c.Count > 0 Then                                 'Check to see if we got a match
    CType(c(0), ComboBox).Items.Add("ABC")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

as per my comment to Mark above his answer works !!!
 This is what I ended up (for future reference)

```
    Public Function TESTloadComboBoxOrHelp(ByRef formName As Form, ByVal boxName As Object, ByVal callingName As String) ', ByVal groupBx)
    'loadComboBoxOrHelp(me,"comboboxname",me.name)
    '
    Dim c As Control() = formName.Controls.Find(boxName, True) 'Search for boxName in parent and all child controls
    If c.Count > 0 Then                                 'Check to see if we got a match
        Try
            conn.Open()
            myCommand.Connection = conn
            Dim query = "SELECT name, lookupValue " _
                    & "FROM lookups " _
                    & "WHERE name = '" & formName.Name.ToString & "." & boxName.ToString & "'"
            myCommand.CommandText = query
            If debug Then evl.WriteToSimpleLog(query, callingName)
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
            While myReader.Read
                CType(c(0), ComboBox).Items.Add(myReader.GetString("lookupValue").ToString)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while retrieving records on table Lookups..." & ex.Message, "Lookups Table")
        Finally
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End If
```

I will try the data binding also that was suggested, I just had not thought of that but this is finally working, I hated my workaround that I had been using